# How can I fill out the space with a div tag in CSS? (Images included)

Tags: html, css

I am a newbie, when it comes to learning HTML and CSS for myself and have been playing around with coding under the guidance of several videos. Obviously, I have to deal with knowledge gaps, by doing it this way.

Anyway, I have "designed" a CSS Layout from my head, so to help me push further in the process of learning. Here is the image, how I would like it to have [Image Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2lQ4.jpg)

The Output of the code looks like this: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EctKn.jpg)

I have been trying to figure out, how I can align a div below the header div on the left and right side, to completely fill out the black spaces.

And my code below:

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.Header {
  height: 191px;
  background: #808080;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.contentwrap {
  width: 1025px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  background: #808080;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 190px;
}

.footer {
  background: #808080;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 129px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Header">
  <h1> Header </h1>
</div>
<div class="contentwrap">
  <div class="container">
    <p> Text </p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p> Text </p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p> text </p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p> text </p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p> footer </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.Header {
  height: 191px;
  background: #808080;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
}

.content__sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.content__sidebar--left {
  background-color: red;
}

.content__sidebar--right {
  background-color: green;
}


.content__main {
  flex: 1;
}

.container {
  background: #808080;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 190px;
}

.footer {
  background: #808080;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 129px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Header">
  <h1> Header </h1>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="content__sidebar content__sidebar--left"></div>
 
  <div class="content__main">
    <div class="container">"
      <p> Text </p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <p> Text </p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <p> text </p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <p> text </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content__sidebar content__sidebar--right"></div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <p> footer </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you elaborate on how you came up with the solution or maybe what I should consider next, when I am trying something similiar? If it not too much ask. I think I have a basic grasp on how it works, but a further explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: @elbertainstein, I suggest to read more info about Flexbox CSS (which I used in my solution to create such layout). Here is the link, please check it out, it contains good explanation of all flexbox properties with some examples: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you very much, I look into it further.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly way: https://codepen.io/stefantigro/pen/bGdZyeX

```html
<div class="Header">
  <h1> Header </h1>
</div>
<div class="">
  <div class="right-side side">

  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="container">
    <p> Text </p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p> Text </p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p> text </p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p> text </p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p> footer </p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="left-side side">

  </div>
</div>
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.Header {
  height: 191px;
  background: #808080;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.contentwrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  background: #808080;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 190px;
  display: block;
}

.footer {
  background: #808080;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 129px;
}

.middle
{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
}

.right-side{
  background: blue;
}

.left-side{

  background: red;
}

.side{
  margin: 0;
  width: 19%;
  height: 800px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Problem here was we are using set dimensions and well size varies especially from monitor to monitor. I would suggest looking into a grid system like bootstrap's or https://960.gs/

Comment: I have already accepted the answer above, as it does the things I want it, for now. But thank you. I have heard of Bootstrap and planned to look into it further, when I am feeling comfortable with basic Html and Css Codes. Is there something specific I have to look for (tags, attributes..) when applying bootstrap, for example, my question?

Comment: I suggest understanding the grid system first and after which just go through the documentation to get familiar with the way bootstrap uses its classes